# Is there any overhead for sharepoint content database for saving a zipfile?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

I am using a sharepoint document library to store some scorm courses.They are in zip file format.When a zipfile is uploaded to the SP content database, and say that file is 100KB, would it get stored in the content database as 100KB or is there any overhead added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first there is Metadata, which is Filename, User, etc. pp. (essentially everything but the file content itself, which you see inside the document library)
Then there might be "shredded storage" (which applies to SP15 only - I think), which is a chunk writing mechanism, which adds more overhead. But both are just some byte - nothing to hassle about.

Btw. this question was for sharepoint.stackexchange.com ;)

Comment: The binary data itself will be the original size.

Comment: So if i upload a zip file having size 100kb then total space needed in database is 100kb plus some bytes for Metadata which is Filename, User etc..Is my conclusion right?

Comment: Yep - but it is more likely some kb than some bytes - look into AllDocouments and DocumentStreams in the content db - there you see everything

Comment: Why don't you test by uploading 100 x 100kb files and checking the DB size?